# Embed Promise within a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm new to both `node.js` and `Promise` functionality so please forgive me if this question is really foolish.

I'm trying to make a child `Promise` call `forEach` child within a Parent call (if that makes sense).

This is my code:

```
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var authorMapArray = new Array
            db.sequelize.query(authorQuery, {
                replacements: queryParams
            }).spread(function(authorSitemap) {
                authorSitemap.forEach(function(obj) {
                    /*
                    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
                        var thisQuery = photoQuery + ' AND author = ' + obj.id.toString();
                        db.sequelize.query(thisQuery, {
                            queryParams
                        }).spread(function(authorImages) {
                            var authorImageArray = new Array;
                            authorImages.forEach(function(obj) {
                                var imgLink = { url: imgHost + obj.img_id + '.jpg', title : img_tags }
                                authorImageArray.push(imgLink);
                            })
                        });
                        resolve(authorImageArray);
                    });
                    */
                    var authorLink = { url: 'author/' + obj.id, /*img: authorImageArray,*/ changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                    siteMapArray.push(authorLink);
                });
                resolve(siteMapArray);

                //and finally create it
                createSiteMap(siteMapArray);
            });
        })
```

You'll note, the section in the middle is commented out.  When I run the code like this I get the results I expect, that is the authorLink added to the sitemap.  When I uncomment the code (in order to include the images associated with the author in the sitemap), not even the authorlinks are added.

How do I get the images for the author included within their record?

**EDIT**

This is the more complete code:

```
function createSiteMap(myURLs) {
    var rows = 10000;
    var totalMaps = Math.trunc(myURLs.length/rows)+1;
    var today = new Date();
    var mySitemaps = new Array;
    for (var i=1; i<totalMaps+1; i++) {
        var filename = "public/sitemap-" + i.toString() + ".xml";
        var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
            hostname: hostname,
            cacheTime: 600000,  //600 sec (10 min) cache purge period 
            urls: myURLs.slice((i-1)*rows,i*rows)
            });
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, sitemap.toString());
        mySitemaps.push(filename);
    }

    // this needs to create sitemap tags not url tags
    var smi = sm.buildSitemapIndex({
        urls: mySitemaps
        });
    fs.writeFileSync("public/sitemap.xml", smi.toString());

    process.exit();
}

function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}

function getPhotos() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var siteMapArray = new Array()        
        var tags = new Array()
        siteMapArray.push ({ url: '/' , changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true, lastmodfile: 'views/home.hbs' },)
        db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
            replacements: queryParams
        }).spread(function(makeSiteMap) {
            makeSiteMap.forEach(function(obj) {
                // images for sitemap
                var img_tags = obj.tags.replace(/,/g , " ");
                var imgLink = { url: imgHost + obj.img_id + '.jpg', title : img_tags }
                var siteLink = { url: 'photo/' + obj.img_id, img: imgLink, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push(siteLink);
                obj.tags = obj.tags.split(',').map(function(e) {
                    return e.trim().split(' ').join('+');
                });
                for (var tag in obj.tags) {
                    tags.push(obj.tags[tag])
                }
            });

            resolve (siteMapArray);

            //tags for sitemap
            var uniqueTags = uniq(tags);
            for (var tag in uniqueTags) {
                var siteLink = { url: '/search/' + uniqueTags[tag], changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push (siteLink);
            }

            //now author tags
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var authorMapArray = new Array
                db.sequelize.query(authorQuery, {
                    replacements: queryParams
                }).spread(function(authorSitemap) {
                    authorSitemap.forEach(function(obj) {
                        /*
                        return new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
                            var thisQuery = photoQuery + ' AND author = ' + obj.id.toString();
                            db.sequelize.query(thisQuery, {
                                queryParams
                            }).spread(function(authorImages) {
                                var authorImageArray = new Array;
                                authorImages.forEach(function(obj) {
                                    var imgLink = { url: imgHost + obj.img_id + '.jpg', title : img_tags }
                                    authorImageArray.push(imgLink);
                                })
                            });
                            resolve(authorImageArray);
                        });
                        */
                        var authorLink = { url: 'author/' + obj.id, /*img: authorImageArray,*/ changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                        siteMapArray.push(authorLink);
                    });
                    resolve(siteMapArray);

                    //and finally create it
                    createSiteMap(siteMapArray);
                });
            })

        });
    });
};

getPhotos();
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's assume that you want something like this:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  // return a promise that resolves to the siteMapArray
}
```

First step would be to rewrite it without using `new Promise()` - you shouldn't be needing this one very often, since most of work with promises is just chaining `.then()` calls which is much more readable.

Note that [`.spread()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) is just a `.then()` with sugar on top. The sugar is not standard `Promise` syntax, but rather an addon from `bluebird` that `sequelize` recommends to use. These are equivalent for a promise that resolves with array with 2 values:

```
something.then(resultArray => ...);
something.spread((resultItem1, resultItem2) => ...);
```

(I'm going to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), is that OK?)

---

So the first step is to get rid of `new Promise()` as promised, before we start incorporating the code from your comments:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  var authorMapArray = new Array();
  return db.sequelize
    .query(authorQuery, {
      replacements: queryParams
    })
    .spread(authorSitemap => {
      authorSitemap.forEach(function(obj) {
        var authorLink = {
          url: "author/" + obj.id,
          /*img: authorImageArray,*/
          changefreq: "weekly",
          priority: 0.6,
          lastmodrealtime: true
        };
        siteMapArray.push(authorLink);
      });
      return siteMapArray;
    });
}
```

Simple enough?

- We use `.query()` to get a promise of results,
- then we use `.then()` or `.spread()` passing a callback that processes the results,
- `spread()` returns a new promise that resolves when we're done with everything, and this promise is the result of `getSiteMapArray()`. It's going to resolve with the value from `return siteMapArray`.

We could simplify one step further with `map()` instead of `forEach` which is recommended whenever you want to transform each element in an array:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  return db.sequelize
    .query(authorQuery, {
      replacements: queryParams
    })
    .spread(authorSitemap => {
      return authorSitemap.map(obj => ({
        url: "author/" + obj.id,
        /*img: authorImageArray,*/
        changefreq: "weekly",
        priority: 0.6,
        lastmodrealtime: true
      }));
    });
}
```

---

So that was the easy part, now how do we incorporate the authorImage query here?

Let me extract a helper first:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  return db.sequelize
    .query(authorQuery, {
      replacements: queryParams
    })
    .spread(authorSitemap => {
      return authorSitemap.map(getAuthorDescription);
    });
}

function getAuthorDescription(obj) {
  return {
    url: "author/" + obj.id,
    /*img: authorImageArray,*/
    changefreq: "weekly",
    priority: 0.6,
    lastmodrealtime: true
  };
}
```

Now `getAuthorDescription` is synchronous, but we want it to do a query on its own, so let's rewrite it to async, so that it returns a promise too!

```
function getAuthorDescription(obj) {
  var thisQuery = photoQuery + " AND author = " + obj.id.toString();
  return db.sequelize
    .query(thisQuery, {
      queryParams
    })
    .spread(function(authorImages) {
      var authorImageArray = new Array();
      authorImages.forEach(function(obj) {
        var imgLink = { url: imgHost + obj.img_id + ".jpg", title: img_tags };
        authorImageArray.push(imgLink);
      });
      return {
        url: "author/" + obj.id,
        img: authorImageArray,
        changefreq: "weekly",
        priority: 0.6,
        lastmodrealtime: true
      };
    });
}
```

Another great case to use `.map()` but I'll leave that one for you.

Back to the original code:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  return db.sequelize
    .query(authorQuery, {
      replacements: queryParams
    })
    .spread(authorSitemap => {
      return authorSitemap.map(getAuthorDescription); // !!!
    });
}
```

Wow, now we're in trouble - `getAuthorDescription` returns a promise, so we're resolving `getSiteMapArray` with a list of promises, instead of list of values!

We need a way to wait for each of the promises returned from `getAuthorDescription` to finish, and obtain an array of collected results of all these promises. This way is called [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

So the code becomes:

```
function getSiteMapArray() {
  return db.sequelize
    .query(authorQuery, {
      replacements: queryParams
    })
    .spread(authorSitemap => {
      return Promise.all(authorSitemap.map(getAuthorDescription));
    });
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Wow!  OK, so I've tried implementing this and it still isn't working.  I think part of the issue is I didn't show all my code because I've actually got another Promise above which I think is causing an issue.  I've added it in an edit, but I'm going to need some time to read through and understand this post. - Thank you

Comment: Careful - I only covered extracting `getSiteMapArray`, after calling and resolving it you'll need to call `createSiteMap()` somewhere in there

Comment: ok - I did add `createSiteMap()` to be called directly after `getSiteMapArray()` but I now realise, I don't think we're adding to `siteMapArray` anywhere in the new code so I need to add that but

Comment: That would be `getSiteMapArray().then(siteMapArray => doSomethingWith(siteMapArray))`

Comment: Brilliant - thank you.  I'm not sure I understand it really well yet but I have it working

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues in your implementation. I will suggest not to use `[].foreach` for child promise. make separate method for child promise and called it for each `authorSitemap` using promise.all.

Below is sample implementation with update.

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var authorMapArray = new Array
            db.sequelize.query(authorQuery, {
                replacements: queryParams
            }).spread(function(authorSitemap) {

                return Promise.all(authorSitemap.map(GetAuthor))
                .then(function(authorImageArray){
                    var authorLink = { url: 'author/' + obj.id, img: authorImageArray, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                    siteMapArray.push(authorLink);
                    createSiteMap(siteMapArray);
                    resolve(siteMapArray);
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    reject(error);
                })
            });
        })

function GetAuthor(obj) {
    return new Promise(function(reject,resolve){
        var thisQuery = photoQuery + ' AND author = ' + obj.id.toString();
        db.sequelize.query(thisQuery, { queryParams})
                    .spread(function(authorImages) {
                            var authorImageArray = new Array;
                            authorImages.forEach(function(obj) {
                                var imgLink = { url: imgHost + obj.img_id + '.jpg', title : img_tags }
                                authorImageArray.push(imgLink);
                            })
                            resolve(authorImageArray);
                        });
    })
}
```

Comment: This is giving me an error: `Unhandled rejection (<[{"url":"https://www.example.com/img-...>, no stack trace)` without any traceback which I need to try and understand